# Oracle SQL Select Where Column equals more than one value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

Pretty straight forward. What is wrong with this statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUST_FNAME "FIRST NAME", CUST_LNAME "LAST NAME", POS_TIME "TIME", POS_DATE "DATE" FROM POS, CUSTOMER
WHERE CUST_NUM = POS_CUST_NUM AND POS_ITEMID = 1 AND POS_ITEMID = 2;
```

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error or not getting the results you want?

Comment: POS_ITEMID = 1 AND POS_ITEMID = 2 will always evaluate to false.

Comment: A single field cannot be 2 things. Do you mean that you want the field when it is either or? In that case you would use POS_ITEMID in (1,2)

Comment: No not getting any syntax errors just getting "no rows selected"

I'm trying to get it to select where the two items are purchased not 1 or the other. Or works just not the results I want and in just returns the same results as or would.

Comment: @Snoopy101x There are a couple ways to solve. One way is INTERSECT, see my query below. You could also aggregate in an inline view and join into that view where the count is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want customers who are associated with BOTH items 1 and 2. In that case you can use the following:

```
select x.*, pos_time, pos_date
  from (SELECT CUST_NUM, CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME
          FROM POS
          join CUSTOMER
            on CUST_NUM = POS_CUST_NUM
         where POS_ITEMID = 1
        intersect
        SELECT CUST_NUM, CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME
          FROM POS
          join CUSTOMER
            on CUST_NUM = POS_CUST_NUM
         where POS_ITEMID = 2) x
  join pos
    on x.cust_num = pos.pos_cust_num
 where pos_itemid in (1, 2)
```

Comment: Yeah I tried IN but it's not returning the what I want, it returns similar to OR

Comment: @Snoopy101x Did you try my intersect query above?

Comment: @Snoopy101x The intersect query above is very different from your original query, that is not the only part I added.

Comment: Tried the first one as you have it and got invalid identifier at x.cust_num and when I change x to customer (the name of the table) I still get invalid identifier.

Comment: @Snoopy101x I added the cust_num field to the above in my edit to it should run now. Let me know if it doesn't. I made some assumptions as to what tables are holding which fields.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I'd kiss you if I could. Yes that absolutely did the trick. Just had to add DISTINCT after the select to make it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this might be a little more efficient than the intersect that Brian did above.  Also, I don't have access to a database right now, so my syntax may be slightly off.

```
select CUST_NUM, CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, pos_time, pos_date
from CUSTOMER c1,POS p1
 where c1.cust_num = p1.pos_cust_num
 and p1.pos_itemid=1
 and exists (select 'x' from 
             pos p2
             where p2.pos_cust_num=p1.pos_cust_num
             and p2.pos_itemid=2)
```

basically, give me everyone where the ordered itemid 1 and where a record exists where the same customer ordered itemid 2.